# How to merge smaller sub-elements into larger parent-elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, but some lists are "sublists" of other lists. What I want to do is remove the sublists from the larger list so that we only have the largest unique sublists.

For example:

```
>>> some_list = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> ideal_list = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
```

The code that I've written right now is:

```
new_list = []

for i in range(some_list)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(some_list)):
        count = 0
        for k in some_list[i]:
            if k in some_list[j]:
                count += 1
        if count == len(some_list[i]):
            new_list.append(some_list[j])
```

The basic algorithm that I had in mind is that we'd check if a list's elements were in the following sublists, and if so then we use the other larger sublist. It doesn't give the desired output (it actually gives `[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 2, 3]]`) and I'm wondering what I could do to achieve what I want.

I don't want to use sets because duplicate elements matter.

Comment: A brute-force algorithm would be: for each list in `some_list`, check if it is a sublist of any other list in `some_list`, and if not, add it to `ideal_list`.

Comment: what would be the desired result for `some_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [3, 4]]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 That would work actually. Perhaps I had the order wrong, I'll take a look into it, thanks.

Comment: @Marat The desired output would be the same as `some_list`, since there are not sublists that are completely inside other sublists.

Comment: Do you care about order, or whether the elements are contiguous in the superlist?  E.g., for `[[1, 2], [1, 3, 2]]` would you want both lists, or just the second?  How about for `[[1, 2], [2, 1, 3]]`?  What about duplicate lists, e.g. `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]`.  Would you want just `[[1, 2]]` for this?

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, order is also important. I think that I've found a solution with help from the first comment. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: If order is important, then you have a significantly different problem.  You need to include your contextual definition of "subset" in your problem specification, and give a test case for which this is significant.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as `set`, but using `Counter` instead. It should be a lot more efficient in sublist check part than brute force

```
from collections import Counter

new_list = []
counters = []
for arr in sorted(some_list, key=len, reverse=True):
    arr_counter = Counter(arr)
    if any((c & arr_counter) == arr_counter for c in counters):
        continue  # it is a sublist of something else
    new_list.append(arr)
    counters.append(arr_counter)
```

Comment: OP explicitly said order is important.  Read the comments.  So this answer is incorrect.  The output for `[[1, 2], [2, 1 3]]` should contain both lists, not just the second.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
l = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
```

One way here:

```
l1 = l.copy()
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        if set(i).issubset(set(j)) and i!=j:
            l1.remove(i)
            break
```

This prints:

```
print(l1) 
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
```

EDIT: (Taking care of duplicates as well)

```
l1 = [list(tupl) for tupl in {tuple(item) for item in l }]
l2 = l1.copy()
for i in l1:
    for j in l1:
        if set(i).issubset(set(j)) and i!=j:
            l2.remove(i)
            break
```

Comment: this does not account for duplicate elements

Comment: Yeah... thanks.. I think a code to remove the duplicates from list of list at the top would do it right

Answer (score 0):

With some inspiration from @mkrieger1's comment, one possible solution would be:

```
def merge_sublists(some_list):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        true_or_false = []
        for j in range(len(some_list)):
            if some_list[j] == some_list[i]:
                continue
            true_or_false.append(all([x in some_list[j] for x in some_list[i]]))
        if not any(true_or_false):
            new_list.append(some_list[i])

    return new_list
```

As is stated in the comment, a brute-force solution would be to loop through each element and check if it's a sublist of any other sublist. If it's *not*, then append it to the new list.

Test cases:

```
>>> merge_sublists([[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4]])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> merge_sublists([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [3, 4]])
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Try it with a duplicate sublist:  `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]`.